# How can i get the list of global picklist translated value using tooling Api?

Tags: tooling-api

Here I have the following end point to get the list of global pick list value.

```
/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=select+id+from+globalvalueset+where+developername='T_Shirts_Size'
```

But i want the list of translated global picklist in tooling api.

I found one solution is that you can use globalValueSetTranslation, but how do I use it in Tooling API?

Comment: You can get translated value in Apex for your picklist field.. ?  will that work?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal No the picklist is different than global picklist.

Comment: were you able to find out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fetch the global picklist translations using Tooling API. There is no resource/object available in Tooling API to fetch the translations for global picklists. Refer to [Tooling API Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm) for the list of all supported objects.

[GlobalValueSetTranslation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvaluesettranslation.htm) is supported with Metadata API and that may be your only route here to be able to fetch the translated values.